# How to get the list of price offers on an item from Amazon with python-amazon-product-api item_lookup function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write a function to get a list of offers (their prices) for an item based on the ASIN:

```
def price_offers(asin):
    from amazonproduct import API, ResultPaginator, AWSError
    from config import AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY
    api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, 'de')
    str_asin = str(asin)
    node = api.item_lookup(id=str_asin, ResponseGroup='Offers', Condition='All', MerchantId='All')
    for a in node:
        print a.Offer.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice
```

I am reading
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?ItemLookup.html and trying to make this work, but all the time it just says:

```
Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: no such child: {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2009-10-01}Offer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like there is no Offer element in your response. Try

```
node = api.item_lookup(...)
from lxml import etree
print etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True)
```

to see how the returned XML looks like.

Answer (score 6):

OK, thanks. To anwser my own question for others who might have the same problem, the right way to do the above is:

```
def price_offers(asin):
    from amazonproduct import API, ResultPaginator, AWSError
    from config import AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY
    api = API(AWS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, 'de')
    str_asin = str(asin)
    node = api.item_lookup(id=str_asin, ResponseGroup='Offers', Condition='All', MerchantId='All')
    for a in node.Items.Item.Offers.Offer:
        print a.OfferListing.Price.FormattedPrice
```

amazonproduct comes from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me. Just to flag I had to set default encoding to utf-8 otherwise the above excerpt struggled with currency symbols